# Wireless network goes down when Windows 10 computer joins

Tags: windows-10, airport-extreme

I upgraded to Windows 10 and now randomly my Airport extreme router (in bridge mode) goes down when the Windows machine connects. The network works fine for months when the machine is on but within five minutes of it being on the connections on all other machines drop and I have to reboot the airport. I tried a different wireless card and it didn't do this with Windows 7 so what's in Windows 10 that's causing this?

Windows machine is up to date, airport is up to date.

The wireless adapters are older so I'm guessing they don't support 5Ghz. LAN cable work fine it's just wifi that brings down the wifi and only when that computer is connected nothing else.

The airport is acting as a bridge to my fios router but it's the only wireless AP in the house. When I connect the Windows machine the wifi breaks but not the LAN.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any firmware updates for the Airport. Are there any Win 10 drivers for the WiFi Card in computer. Are you connecting to the 5Ghz? Try connecting at the 2.4Ghz. Turn off encryption. Try connecting to the RJ-45 port.

Comment: IP address conflict with the Airport?

Comment: Exactly which model number of AirPort Extreme? Exactly which firmware version is it running?

Comment: Sounds like an IP address conflict somewhere

Comment: I can confirm this happening to 3 of my windows machines out of 4. Different connections (one cabled, others wifi)

Comment: Try to run ip scan and check if router don't have same ip as your computer.

Comment: Try to turn off IPv6 on the router. Questions: (1) Do you have a wired connection on the same router?. (2) Did you upgrade the router's firmware when the problem started? (3) Is guest WiFi activated? (Try to deactivate if it is).

Comment: @SamuelTulach this happens with 3 machines, I have a network scanner running constantly (FingBox) and no, none of them has same address of the router

Comment: @harrymc In my case: IPv6 was off, now I tried to turn it on (1) yes, one of the machines is via wire, 2 are via wify. (2) Might be, but also not. I started noticing it, as I began adding windows PCs to the network, before I didn't have any, so I couldn't test. PCs where added to the network after the last update. (3) No, I will describe my situation below.

Comment: In my case, there are 3 Airports on a WDS network: one is an express the two others are extreme (N). The network starts from one Extreme in the office that is connected with a long range antenna to the other Extreme at home at 2.4GHz in Wds, then this last Extreme is connected to the Express via 2.4Ghz and the latter also has a 5Ghz network enabled. Everything is smooth until you turn on some 2-3 of the Windows PCs, when that happens all the network goes down. If I reset all the bases most of the times it returns to working condition.

Comment: I even have a relay connected to a small PC+Arduino that resets the office Airport when the link is down (if it doesn't detect devices with the home Airport MAC address on the network for 10 minutes it switches the office Airport down and up). This partially solved the problem on the office side, but sometimes I still have to reset the home Airports. And this happens after Win 10 PCs power up (not always, but most of the times). For some unknown reason one PC is immune to all this :|

Comment: IP addresses are mostly given with DHCP, with a few exceptions. Some devices follow DHCP but always get a fixed IP address, based on their MAC. I set thei IP in the Airport Utility DHCP panel. One device I have no control of has a fixed IP, and I give it that same fixed address in the DHCP prefs of the Airport Utility, hoping this will keep that IP away from other DHCP devices

Comment: IPv6 was on local link only for all 3 bases, now I will try with it on for some time. Guest network is off. 5GHz network is on only on the last base

Comment: fiber --- Extreme1  <-- 2.4 --> Extreme2 <-- 2.4 --> Express <-- 5+2.4 -->

Comment: The "cabled" PC is connected via Ethernet wire to the Extreme2, one PC via 5Ghz to the Express. Others move around. Similar PCs in the office connected to the Extreme1 have no problems. That's all, no more spamming, sorry for the length

Comment: Does it work better without the wired connection? Sometimes there is a conflict from an echo effect.

Comment: @harrymc Does the echo effect happen even if the cabled PC is turned OFF? Because the PC is always connected but most of the time it is OFF and the mess happens even when it's OFF and I turn ON the other PC (connected to the other base via Wifi). Other devices Wii U, Android Phones, MacBooks have no problems in the same situation. Only Win10 causes havoc.

Comment: If there is light on the adapter on the PC side then there could be a problem. It's a long shot, but try to disconnect the cable.